# How to bind an empty list to a ComboBox and add items later?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox that I bind to a list data source.  The list starts off empty and later I want to add items to it.  The problem is that when I add the first item, I get ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Anybody have a work around?

This exact same issue is described here, but I am not sure if it was ever resolved.

[combobox--bindingsource-possible-bug](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-data-controls-databinding/combobox--bindingsource-possible-bug-28329.shtml)

Here is the code from that post:

```
BindingList<int> bl = new BindingList<int>();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
this.Controls.Add(cb);
cb.DataSource = bs;
bs.DataSource = bl;
//bs.DataError += delegate { throw new Exception("DataError"); };
bl.Add(99);
```

And the resulting stack trace:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectedIndex.set(int value) + 0x1e8 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DataManager_PositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x36 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged(System.EventArgs e) + 0x39 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(int newPosition, bool validating, bool endCurrentEdit, bool firePositionChange, bool pullData) + 0x16a bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x2f9 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x82 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x2e bytes 
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<int>.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x17 bytes  
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<int>.InsertItem(int index, int item) + 0x62 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<int>.Add(int item) + 0x36 bytes  
WindowsFormsApplication1.exe!WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 35 + 0x10 bytes   C#
```

Comment: I work with WPF but I bind to and empty ObservableCollection and add items later.

Comment: @Blam if only he was using WPF

Answer (score 0):

Once the ComboBox is bound, it is not able to add any value which is not in the data source. I would recommend you add the new items into the data source and re-bind the ComboBox every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArraList.Adapter like this -

Drag a combobox control on a winforms app and include  this code:

```
    var items = ArrayList.Adapter(comboBox1.Items);

    items.Add("TestSample1");
```

Here, you are adding the items later.